# Harmonic Bergman spaces on graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, potential-theory

Harmonic Bergman spaces on Euclidean domains are a set of harmonic functions on a domain that are from $L^{p}$ of that domain. I tried to find something on harmonic Bergman spaces on graphs because we have harmonic functions on graphs. I proved that this makes sanse to consider, but I didn't find anything already proved. Did someone considered the same theory earlier?